# service "redis" refers to undefined volume redis-dev: invalid compose project

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis

This is my docker compose file where I have redis service and volume declared dynamically

```
redis:
  container_name: redis-${ENV}
  image: redis
  command: --port ${REDIS_PORT}
  ports:
    - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
  volumes:
    - redis-${ENV}:/data
  networks:
    - app

volumes:
  redis:
    name: redis-${ENV}
    external: false
```

I get error: `service "redis" refers to undefined volume redis-dev: invalid compose project`

Comment: Probably a wrong copy&paste, I guess your `redis` section should be within a `services` section.
Once fixed that, I do not get your error. I get `service "redis" refers to undefined network app`, which is correct because it is not defined here.
I understand if you want to simplify your original file, but you should make sure others can run it, to test.

Answer (score 0):

Once I make your `docker-compose.yml` workable, by removing the undefined `app` network, which is not relevant, and adding the missing `services` section:

```
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis-${ENV}
    image: redis
    command: --port ${REDIS_PORT}
    ports:
      - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis-${ENV}:/data

volumes:
  redis:
    name: redis-${ENV}
    external: false
```

I get your same output:

```bash
$ docker-compose config
service "redis" refers to undefined volume redis-env: invalid compose project
```

I think the problem is that you assumed that you could refer to this volume by the value of its `name` property. That is just a label, but its identifier is still `redis`, which cannot be interpolated with environment variables (no key can, only values).

In other words, I don't think what you wanted to do can be done, at least not just within the `docker-compose.yml` file. You can achieve this by creating the volume externally and then using it as an external volume.

Answer (score 0):

These two names need to match:

```yaml
services:
  redis:
  volumes:
    - redis-${ENV}:/data
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^

volumes:
  redis:
# ^^^^^
```

Note that Compose is able to construct volume and container names itself.  It uses a [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_project_name) as part of the name, and so the generated names wind up looking a lot like what you've specified, so long as you use a `docker-compose -p dev` option or similar.  You can probably remove the manual name settings and the mentions of `${ENV}` throughout the file.

If you also let each Redis instance use its standard port 6379 inside its container (the container network isolation means there won't be a conflict) and use the Compose-provided `default` network, you can reduce this to as little as

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "${REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

volumes:
  redis:
```